# How to prevent keyboard hiding in UITextView when send button is tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I've UITextView, next to it and separate from text view is a send button. After user types text in text view and taps send button, keyboard hides. I don't want to hide keyboard after user taps on send button. How do I achieve this?

Updating question to provide more details.
1) Send Button is a separate UIButton.
2) I don't have any resignFirstResponder being called exclusively in the code. 
3) After send button is clicked I've following code which shows/hides keyboard.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Setup keyboard event
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

// Setup keyboard event
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){
    print("keyboardWillShow")
    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)

    var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
    contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){
    print("keyboardWillHide")
    let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
}
```

Send button clicked code

```
@IBAction func sendButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Disable textview and send button while message is being sent
    messageTextView.isEditable = false
    sendButton.isEnabled = false

    fetchSendMessage( ) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            ShowDialog.showDialog(title: nil, message: (error?.localizedDescription)!, viewController: self)
        } else {
            if (result?.success)! {
                self.arry = (result?.data)!

                self.fetchMessages(page: 1, completed: {
                    self.insertNewMessage(sentMessage)
                })

                // Clear the message & Enable textview and send button
                self.messageTextView.isEditable = true
                self.messageTextView.text = "Type Message"
                self.messageTextView.textColor = UIColor.greyColour
                self.sendButton.isEnabled = true
                self.messageTextView.endEditing(true)
            } else {
                ShowDialog.showDialog(title: "Message not sent", message: (result?.errors![0].message)!, viewController: self)

                // Retain typed message
                // Enable textview and send button
                self.messageTextView.isEditable = true
                self.sendButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great question. Could you please, however, provide your current code and any attempts you've made.

Comment: When you set `textView.returnKeyType = .send`, the Send key still inserts a newline into the text view and does not dismiss the keyboard. Can you detail your view setup?

Comment: Find the place where :  textView.resignFirstResponder(). If textView won't resign, the keyboard should not hide.

Comment: I can't find any resignFirstResponder in my code.

Comment: Sorry, it's not the return key thingy. I've a separate Send button (UIButton).

Comment: Share your code on button click

Comment: I've added sendButtonClicked code.

Comment: Remove `self.messageTextView.endEditing(true)`. `endEditing(_:)` forces the first responder to resign subsequently hiding the keyboard. If you want to disable the text view from user interaction you should do `messageTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` instead.

Comment: I already tried that, It didn't work either. Please read my updated question again. I've Notification observers added in viewDidLoad which are called to hide keyboard after send button is clicked. I'm not sure what trigger these notification. I think this is the one which is hiding keyboard after Send button is clicked.

Comment: If u r satisfy with my answer, Kindly give tick mark and upvote. So it will be helpful for our SO followers. @Dan

Answer (score 1):

When we are trying to disable `UITextView's` editable option or UserInteraction, automatically keyboard get hides.

Instead of doing this,

```
messageTextView.isEditable = false
```

**Way 2:**

You can create `UIView` and addSubView to `UIWindow`, that will not hide keyboard and also user cannot type.

```
var overView : UIView? // GLOBAL DECLARATION

func addOverView() { // CALL THIS WHEN SEND BUTTON CLICKED

   let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
   overView = UIView(frame: window.bounds)
   overView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.4)

   let windowCount = UIApplication.shared.windows.count
   UIApplication.shared.windows[windowCount-1].addSubview(overView!)
}

func removeOverView() { // CALL THIS WHEN RESPONSE RECEIVED

    overView?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

**Output Way 2:**

[image]

**Way 1:**

Use `UTextView Delegate`,

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if isSendBtnClicked == true {

        return false
    }


    return true
}



@IBAction func sendButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Disable textview and send button while message is being sent
    self.isSendBtnClicked = true
    sendButton.isEnabled = false

    fetchSendMessage( ) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            ShowDialog.showDialog(title: nil, message: (error?.localizedDescription)!, viewController: self)
        } else {
            if (result?.success)! {
                self.arry = (result?.data)!

                self.fetchMessages(page: 1, completed: {
                    self.insertNewMessage(sentMessage)
                })

                // Clear the message & Enable textview and send button
                self.isSendBtnClicked = false
                self.messageTextView.text = "Type Message"
                self.messageTextView.textColor = UIColor.greyColour
                self.sendButton.isEnabled = true
                self.messageTextView.endEditing(true)
            } else {
                ShowDialog.showDialog(title: "Message not sent", message: (result?.errors![0].message)!, viewController: self)

                // Retain typed message
                // Enable textview and send button
                self.isSendBtnClicked = false
                self.sendButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once user click, send button, Keyboard will not hide and user can type but it will not enter in that textview untill response receive from `fetchSendMessage()`

Comment: Here, it is working for me, Did u delete this line? messageTextView.isEditable = false

Comment: Ok I've tried it once again and it does work however it breaks my other things. 1) It doesn't hide keyboard when tapped around. 2) I'm returning character count inside shouldChangeTextIn which it breaks. Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: messageTextView.isEditable = false ,, tell me why u need this exactly? Then I will try to give any other solution.

Comment: This is to prevent user entering into text view and writing another message while one is being sent to server.

Comment: I have updated my answer, kindly check it, it may give some idea.

Comment: I also has similar issue, removing textView.isEditable = false worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can override a method in UITextViewDelegate

```
func textViewShouldEndEditing(UITextView) -> Bool
```

Have this method return false and the UITextView shouldn't resign first responder, ie close the keyboard.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. This function is called after I click send button but keyboard still hides.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that it doesn't work if text view editing is being ended by some other call.

Comment: Just found out that this will break keyboard showing again if you have implemented drag to dismiss keyboard.